# Dates and Charting

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sets of data and each has two columns.
The first column is Date and second column is Price. The dates are formatted different with each data set eg. Gold's date(1951), Money Supply M2's date (1951-01), and Money Sup. M3 Date (9/01/1951)

**What i need:**

I want to chart these with dates on x-axis and price on y-axis

**Questions:**

- do i need to make Gold's Date(YYYY) and Money Supply M2's Date(YYYY-MM) a date object?
- if so how?
- do i need to place all dates in one column and create a sub to help sort the Price with appropriate Date?

Does this make sense?

Comment: You don't get rep points for comments (not to mention most people here don't +1 pointless comments)

Comment: Gotcha.  I figured it was worth a shot ;)

Comment: If the dates are formatted differently then you can still chart them together.  If they're dates stored as text then you'll need to convert them to dates.  Probably best done in formulas using =DATE() which will let you supply the individual year, month and day values.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I just created a custom function, using the built-in DateSerial() function, that looped through all the dates and converted them. This accomplished what i was looking for!

Comment: @Wallace that sounds like a great solution, you should post the code as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have very little experience programming in VBA and was having a hard time finding info on using dates.  I came across an Answer,  given by the person who edited this (brettdj), that listed a few extremely helpful sights on VBA programming for excel. One of those had info on the DateSerial() function. I was then able to throw together some code to quickly fix my problem.

Sub CreateDates()

```
Dim dt As Date
Dim s As String

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7:A27080").Cells
    s = Len(c.Value)

    If s = 4 Then '(YYYY)
        dt = DateSerial(s, 7, 1)
        c.Value = dt
    End If

    If s = 7 Then '(YYYY-MM)
        y = Left(s, 4)
        m = Right(s, 2)
        dt = DateSerial(y, m, 1)
        c.Value = dt
    End If

Next c
```

End Sub

I could probably spend some time and add some regular expressions and make a one-size fits most, but this will work as i want have to use it very often.